# How can I sniff/capture submitted form data in IE?

Tags: website, forms, post

I filled out an online form which is submitting to a crashed ASP.NET app. If I refresh, I get the message:

> To display the webpage again, Internet Explorer
>   needs to resend the information you've
>   previously submitted.
>
> If you were making a purchase, you
>   should click Cancel to avoid a
>   duplicate transaction. Otherwise,
>   click Retry to display the webpage
>   again.

This leads me to believe that the form data I filled out is still in IE's memory. How can I get to it? I tried digging with Fiddler. I can see the request but can't find a way to see the actual form data.

Comment: Crap I can find something for Firefox, but not for IE :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have Fiddler 2 installed and just tried it with a page that asks me to repost data.  I can see all of the session information in the top Session Inspector tab.  TextView shows a raw format and WebForms shows a table with each name-value pair.  You can even build your own response.  I use the IE Developer Toolbar for mostly HTML or CSS help, with images and tables, but Fiddler for the protocol stuff.

Comment: Agreed, Fiddler rocks. Here's the link: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 2):

Try installing [Web Development Helper](http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper). I think you can see the posted content with that tool.

Answer (score 2):

There is the IE developer toolbar available from microsoft. It has all the data required.

Wikipedia link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Toolbar

Comment: Wow they have one of their own now. I've always used Web Development Helper. Here's the download link for completeness ;-) http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en

Comment: It's especially nice that it's built in to IE 8 and 9.

Answer (score 2):

The IE Developer Toolbar and Fiddler2 tools already suggested are are worthwhile.

I also like the [TamperIE](http://www.bayden.com/TamperIE/) add-on for this type of troubleshooting, specifically when form values are what you're looking for.  Essentially, when enabled TamperIE lets you see *and modify* the query string and form variables in any GET or POST request.

One more IE add-on worth mentioning is [ieHttpHeaders](http://www.blunck.se/iehttpheaders/iehttpheaders.html).  While generally useful for viewing the request and response header sequence, it also has the ability to show the request body (i.e. POST form variables, etc.)